Stream OpenAI response with FastAPI and Javascript
I have a FastAPI endpoint that manages the calls to OpenAI's LLMs, and streams it using FastAPI StreamingResponse. From the FastAPI side, this the (simplified) code I'm using:
def call_llm(messages):
    response = call_openai(messages,"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125")
    if response:
        texto = ''
        for ch in response:
            delta = ch.choices[0].delta if ch.choices else None
            if delta and delta.content:
                texto += delta.content
                texto_html = markdown2html(texto)
                print([texto_html])
                yield texto_html
                # time.sleep(0.5)
@app.post('/acordao_chat')
def acordao_chat(conversation_history: ConversationHistory,
                       acordao_id: str = Query(...),
                       token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)
                       ):
    with httpx.Client() as client:
        response = client.get(f'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token={token}')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            if data["aud"] == CLIENT_ID:
                # Use acordao_id for your logic here
                return StreamingResponse(generate_llm_reply(acordao_id,conversation_history), media_type='text/event-stream')
            else:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Unauthorized")
        else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Unauthorized")

On the client side, I'm fetching the stream with the following javascript:
function displayMessages() {
    const chatBoxBody = document.getElementById('chat-box-body');
    chatBoxBody.innerHTML = `
          <div class="chat-box-body" id="chat-box-body">
            <div class="chat-box-instruction">
              <p>Insira uma questão sobre este acórdão.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-box-message">
            </div>
          </div>
`;
    conversationHistory['messages'].forEach(messageObj => {
        const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
        messageElement.className = `chat-box-message ${messageObj.role === 'user' ? 'user-message' : 'bot-message'}`;
        messageElement.innerHTML = `${messageObj.content}`;
        chatBoxBody.appendChild(messageElement);
    });
    chatBoxBody.scrollTop = chatBoxBody.scrollHeight; // Scroll to the bottom
}


async function getBotResponse() {
    const auth_token = '{{ acordao.auth_token }}';
    const acordao_id = '{{ acordao.id }}';

    try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://${ip_address}:8000/acordao_chat?acordao_id=${acordao_id}`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(conversationHistory)
        });
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        let done = false;
        let botMessage = '';

        while (!done) {
            const { value, done: streamDone } = await reader.read();
            done = streamDone;
            if (value) {
                botMessage = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
                console.log("Bot message:", botMessage);
                // if the last message is from user, then add a new message, otherwise update the last message
                if (conversationHistory['messages'][conversationHistory['messages'].length - 1].role === 'user') {
                    conversationHistory['messages'].push({ content: botMessage, role: 'assistant' });
                } else {
                    conversationHistory['messages'][conversationHistory['messages'].length - 1].content = botMessage;
                }
                displayMessages();
            }
            if (done) {

                displayMessages();
            }
            console.log("conversationHistory:", conversationHistory);
            
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching bot response:', error);
    }
}

My problem is that this only works if I force a slow stream (for example with sleep). If I turn off the "slow stream" (disabling time.sleep), the js part starts to repeat the message several times.
Perhaps, this is related to the fact the stream is not being received synchronously? If so, how do I make sure that I update the new message synchronously in respect to the received stream?
